# Correct way to check if Windows is 64 bit or not, on runtime? (C++)

Tags: c++, registry

```
bool Win64bit = (sizeof(int*) == 8) ? 1 : 0;
```

I need this so my app can use Windows registry functions properly (or do i need?).

So am i doing it right ?

Comment: No real need for the "?1:0" part, if you're sticking it in a bool. (Don't know about the rest.)

Comment: Avoid bypassing registry virtualization, it is rarely ever needed.

Comment: what do you mean? i want to be sure my app can use the registry in 64 bit windows too, thats why i need to know which version is running my program, so i can choose the correct registry functions (they use different functions for 32 and 64 bits)

Comment: Please see my comment regarding registry redirection below

Comment: "bool Win64bit = (sizeof(int*) == 8) ? 1 : 0;" tells you if the executing program is compiled to 64-bit or not.  It doesn't tell you the bitness of the Windows OS it runs on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's what Raymond Chen suggests in his blog at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050201-00/?p=36553:

```cpp
BOOL Is64BitWindows()
{
    #if defined(_WIN64)
        return TRUE;  // 64-bit programs run only on Win64
    #elif defined(_WIN32)
        // 32-bit programs run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows
        // so must sniff
        BOOL f64 = FALSE;
        return IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f64) && f64;
    #else
        return FALSE; // Win64 does not support Win16
    #endif
}
```

Comment: hmm that looks good, didnt understand the logic perfectly, isnt the BOOL f64 = FALSE; useless? shouldnt BOOL f64; be enough?

Comment: That's trouble, IsWow64Process() is not exported by kernel32.dll on older versions of Windows. The program won't run.  Use GetProcAddress().

Comment: how old versions are you talking about? win95? win98?

Comment: @Newbie: nobugz was rigth, to make the code above robust you should use something like: "fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS)GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),"IsWow64Process");
  
    if (NULL != fnIsWow64Process)
    {
        if (!fnIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(),&bIsWow64))
        {
            // handle error
        }
    }"

Comment: @Newbie: "how old versions are you talking about?" It is exported since WinXP SP2

Answer (score 7):

No, this cannot work as a *run-time check*, since `sizeof(int*)` is fixed at compile time at the point where you choose to compile your program as either 32-bit or 64-bit, and once compiled, the check will have the same fixed result regardless of which platform you are running it on.

However, since a 64-bit program cannot run on a 32-bit platform, you will find that your check works correctly *without modification* as a compile-time check:

If you compile your program as 64-bit, your program will use the 64-bit API because of your code above, and will work correctly on a 64-bit version of windows.  It will fail to run on 32-bit windows at all, so there will be no chance you accidentally use the 64-bit API on a 32-bit version of windows.

```
v++ platform == 64-bit => sizeof(int*) == 8 => use 64-bit API
AND
( windows platform == 64-bit => 64-bit API works
  OR
  windows platform == 32-bit => program does not run )
```

If you compile your program in 32-bit mode, your program will correctly use the 32-bit APIs, which will work on a 64-bit windows platform in 32-bit compatibility mode, and will obviously work on a 32-bit platform.

```
v++ platform == 32-bit => sizeof(int*) == 4 => use 32-bit API
AND
( windows platform == 64-bit => 32-bit API works using compatibility mode
  OR
  windows platform == 32-bit => 32-bit API works )
```

If you really want to access 64-bit APIs from a 32-bit program I daresay there are APIs to do it, but I'm not sure that you would want to.

Comment: i just need to know which one of the functions to use RegDeleteKeyEx() or RegDeleteKey() thats why i need this check. Also even if i just needed one function, the function still needs value depending on which OS it is: KEY_WOW64_32KEY or KEY_WOW64_64KEY ... so im stuck if i dont know how to get the windows version.

Comment: @Newbie: are you sure you need to know that? I mean, do you really need to delete particular WOW64_64_KEY? Because otherwise it is worth mentioning that WoW64 makes use of a registry redirector that "isolates 32-bit and 64-bit applications by providing separate logical views of key portions of the registry on WOW64"

Comment: oh so i could just use the 32 bit registry functions anyways? and 64 bit windows can handle it properly?

Answer (score 4):

In addition, one can use [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx) to check whether you're a 32Bit process (`sizeof(void*)==4`) running under the WoW64 emulation on a 64bit Windows machine.

Comment: The compiler does not know. At least not if you want to find out whether you're running on 64Bit Windows.

Comment: I think each answers a different side of the question: +1.

Comment: The compiler does NOT know if the app is being run on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: at docs: "If the process is a 64-bit application running under 64-bit Windows, the value is also set to FALSE." doesnt this mean my program will think its 32 bit windows now if i compile it on 64 bit machine and run it on 64 bit machine? i dont get it whats the point returning false in that case... btw i dont want the compiler to know, i need to check on runtime.

Comment: If you're compiling for 64Bits, `sizeof(void*)==8` holds. In this case, there is no need to call `IsWow64Process`.

Comment: @John - yes it knows, it is generating 64-bit code.  A program containing 64-bit machine code is guaranteed not to run on a 32-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:
[GetSystemWow64Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724405(v=vs.85).aspx)  - "Retrieves the path of the system directory used by WOW64. This directory is not present on 32-bit Windows." and "On 32-bit Windows, the function always fails, and the extended error is set to ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED."
About IsWow64Process I personally am not sure about the usage of since in MSDN in the description of the IsWow64Process there is the text "Note that this technique is not a reliable way to detect whether the operating system is a 64-bit version of Windows because the Kernel32.dll in current versions of 32-bit Windows also contains this function."

Comment: I think you misunderstood. They were referring to the check whether `IsWow64Process` is present or not as a way to detect the bitness. You also have to call it.