# Determining OS type in PowerBuilder.

Tags: powerbuilder

How to determine if OS is 64 bit or 32bit in PowerBuilder?

Is it possible to obtain it using GetEnvironment?

Comment: Just to expand on the problem a little. A 64-bit process can't run on a 32-bit OS. So, what you have is a 32-bit program that needs to know if it is running on a 32-bit OS or a 64-bit OS. If it's a 32-bit app running on 64-bit Windows, then Windows will run it Wow64 mode. RealHowTo's answer below explains how to check this. There's a blog post from Raymond Chen about detecting 32/64 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ detect 32-bit or 64-bit of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011071/c-detect-32-bit-or-64-bit-of-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetEnvironment` can give some info regarding the cpu via its `CPUType` property, but it will only return the platform type (alpha, mips, pentium, ...).

You can test some remarkable value from the environment that is defined only on a 64b platform, like `ProgramFiles(x86)` by using `GetContextService` / `GetContextKeywords` and setting the environment variable as the queried context keyword:

```
string ls_vals[], ls_val, ls_env = "ProgramFiles(x86)" /*name of the env variable to query*/
ContextKeyword lcxk_base

GetContextService("Keyword", lcxk_base)
lcxk_base.GetContextKeywords(ls_env, ls_vals[])
if upperbound(ls_vals[]) > 0 then
   ls_val = ls_vals[1]
else
   ls_val = "*undefined*" //it is 32b
end if

messagebox ("architecture", ls_val)
```

I would have advised at first to test for the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable, that is `AMD64` in the shell for a windows 64b, but it seems that a PB executable gets `x86`...

Answer (score 8):

Checking an environment variable is easy but it's not bullet proof since a user can redefine the value.

A more robust approach is to check if the current Powerbuilder process is running in WOW64 mode (the 32bit emulation mode).

```
[Local external definitions]
FUNCTION long IsWow64Process(long hwnd, ref  boolean Wow64Process) &
    LIBRARY "Kernel32.DLL"

FUNCTION long GetCurrentProcess ()  LIBRARY "KERNEL32.DLL"

[Powerscript]
boolean wow64 =false
IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), wow64)
MessageBox("Running in 64b env", wow64)
```

Comment: This is the approach I took. I ended up wrapping mine into a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free code from Roland Smith's site.

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_osversion.html

"This program returns information about the version of the operating system. It returns the operating system name, edition and service pack. It also has a function to return version strings from .dll and .exe files."