# Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection on 32-bit Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, 32bit-64bit

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio C++ which needs to run natively as a 32-bit process on any computer running Windows XP 32-bit, or any later Windows operating system.  This program needs to be able to access the `C:\Windows\system32\` folder on a computer, regardless of whether the program is running on a 64-bit or 32-bit system.  To do this, I was using `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` to disable the redirection that Windows typically does to 32-bit processes, sending them to `C:\Windows\syswow64`.  Unfortunately, this breaks compatibility -- though my program can run on Server 2003 and XP x64 edition, the program fails whenever it runs on a 32-bit XP RTM system, giving me this error:

```
[Program Name] - Entry Point Not Found
  The procedure entry point Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection could not be located
  in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.
```

Since the system is 32-bit, the call is obviously superfluous, but I can't figure out a way to determine at runtime whether a system is 64-bit or not, and therefore whether or not to skip the call, without adding another call that itself breaks compatibility, such as `IsWow64Process()`, which requires XP Service Pack 2.

**tl;dr:** How can I determine whether a system is 64-bit or 32-bit without using any of the calls that were introduced after the advent of consumer 64-bit Windows.

Comment: As in something like `GetProcAddress`, then test if the function is there?

Comment: test for the presence of a syswow64 directory? it obviously wouldn't be present on a 32bit windows.

Comment: @Marc-b That's clever, but I have no guarantee that the user won't create one.  It would be dumb, but users can be dumb.

Comment: @Niall That's probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: Bunch of ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011071/detect-32-bit-or-64-bit-of-windows

Comment: @MarcB The problem with `IsWow64Process()`, which most of the people there are suggesting, is as I say in my question, that it was not implemented until SP2.  There are some other clever answers there though.

Comment: @dr_andonuts: You do realize that having `if (magic_is_64bit()) Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection();` in your code will not stop Windows from trying to resolve the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` import on a 32-bit system, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go ahead and use `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`, but don't import it statically.  Instead use either dynamic binding (`GetProcAddress`) or delay-loading, either of which allow you to handle a missing function without crashing (or worse, not even starting, which is the current case).

And just don't worry about the system bitness.  If the function is present, call it.

```
typedef BOOL WINAPI fntype_Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(PVOID *OldValue);
auto pfnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection = (fntype_Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection*)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection");

if (pfnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection) {
   // function found, call it via pointer
   PVOID arg;
   (*pfnWow64DisableWow64FsRedirection)(&arg);
}
else {
   // function was missing
}
```

Now the linker won't find an unresolved symbol named `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`, so it won't put that function in the import table, and Windows won't go looking for it during process startup.

Comment: Unfortunately, statically linking my program would lend itself to another slew of problems, as my program uses the VC++ runtime library, which needs to be statically linked for other reasons.  Is there a way in VC++ to keep static linking, but force dynamic linking at that one instance?

Comment: @dr_andonuts: I didn't say to change how you import the C++ runtime.  Just this one function.  Don't call it by name.  Instead get a pointer from `GetProcAddress`, and call it by pointer.