# Why cpuid returns the wrong answer?

Tags: c++, cpuid

When I run this I get that my system is 32-bit but I am running an Intel 7700k cpu which is a 64-bit even in control panel it says the windows arch is 64bit

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <intrin.h>

using namespace std;

bool check_cpu()
{
    int CPUINFO[4] = {0};
    __cpuid(CPUINFO,0);
    bool b64 = (CPUINFO[3] & 0x20000000 ) || false;

    if (b64)
    {
        cout << "System is 64bit "<< endl;
        return b64;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "System is 32bit "<< endl;
        return b64;
    }
}



int main()
{
    check_cpu();
    return 0;

}
```

what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Assuming that the `0` in the `__cpuid` call is the value that gets passed in `eax` for the actual call, then `0` means "get vendor id". Have you checked the actual values returned in the `CPUINFO` array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/cpuid-cpuidex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) uses the same thing

Comment: Yes the example uses `0`. To get the vendor id. What resource or reference have you otherwise used? Where did you get this check from?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do you suggest i do

Comment: [Detect 32-bit or 64-bit of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011071/detect-32-bit-or-64-bit-of-windows)?

Comment: Why do you think bit `0x20000000` of ECX returned from CPUID(0) implies 64 bit? Which documentation are you following to assume that?

Comment: why do you use `bool b64 = (CPUINFO[3] & 0x20000000 ) || false` instead of `bool b64 = !!(CPUINFO[3] & 0x20000000)`?

Comment: @phuclv Probably because double-negation like that is rather obscure, especially for beginners.

Comment: The checl `CPUINFO[3] & 0x20000000` seems to be correct, but the information required seems to be returned by `__cpuid(CPUINFO,0x80000001)`, not by `__cpuid(CPUINFO,0)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but that's a "standard" way to convert to bool and is very commonly used in many places like the Linux kernel

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yeah. With EAX=0 on the CPUID call, EDX (= `cpuInfo[3]`) will be the `ineI` characters from "GenuineIntel".

Comment: @phuclv And the linux kernel is the "standard" way to learn C(++) programming?